# Drag and Drop in ASP .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drag-and-drop

What is the simplest way to integrate drag and drop functionality?

I will have, for example a list of cases, and a list of employees and I will need to assign a case to one or more employees (among other things).

It looks complicated to do this type of task.

Is there a library or something that simplifies this?

How is it normally implemented?

Comment: This is client functionality, the simplest way may be with simple javascript, or the new html5, the more better is if you use jQuery or Yahoo library YUI.

Comment: It is client functionality that modifies things server side though.

Comment: lookup the asp.net ajax control toolkit (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)

Comment: After the client ends, you send the modifications to the server with a post back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966301/how-to-write-the-code-for-drag-and-drop-items-from-listbox-in-asp-net-using-vb-n/13967697#13967697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use JQuery and JQuery UI, which has a [draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) to configure this.  There is nothing inherently built-in to ASP.NET.

To enable dragging, it's as simple as `$( "#draggable" ).draggable();`, where the #draggable is the ID of the element to drag.  You can also customize the options for when dragging can be enabled, etc.